# What I need to know to travel to Canada for Christmas

Tags: canada, uk-citizens

I want to visit a friend in Canada over Christmas. I am a British Citizen and I have a UK passport and am aware I need an Electronic Travel Authorization. Are there any other requirements I need to visit?

Also, are there any days that are best to book flights?

Comment: You don't really need much more than your passport, eTA, and your tickets.  The border service will likely ask you why you're coming and you'll need a plausible response, which you apparently have.  You'll often find better fares on Tuesdays and Wednesdays, as there are fewer travelers on those days, but around the holidays there might be less of a difference.

Comment: Also if you're going to be staying at a hotel rather than with your friend you'll want to bokk accommodation now as well. Dont be surprised to see higher than normal fares and rates since it will be the holiday season and one of the peak travel times of the year.

Comment: A warm jacket might be a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Flights

It's going to be expensive. Christmas is a busy period so you want to start looking now, the 26th is a holiday here too so that also drives prices up. You may want to come a few days to a week before Christmas and leave after New Year's to save on your fare.

#### Documents

As a British citizen all you need to request entry is your [passport](http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html) and your [eTA](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp).

#### Extra

December in Canada can be cold to brutal depending where you're going and what you're used to. We heat a lot indoors (unlike in parts of northern Europe for example) so bring layers and good insulation for outside.

Just like for flights, accommodation will be more expensive around this time as well (if you're not staying with your friend). So book it as soon as you can.

In case you want to drive or rent a car, you can do so with your [regular full UK license](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/canada/safety-and-security#road-travel) (no need for an international driving permit). Just be sure you're comfortable driving in icy or snowy conditions.

Comment: "Unlike in Europe": I'm not sure what parts of Europe *you've* been to in the winter, but I can assure you that there are certainly parts of Europe with ample and even excessive indoor heating.

Comment: @phoog corrected, I was thinking of Stockholm, Berlin and Paris. Our heating is still excessive compared to those places

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. If the friend I am visiting is actually more than just a friend, will that make a difference? I'd be staying with them so I don't need to worry about accommodation.

Comment: @BeautifulChaos immigration might be concerned you might not leave. If you mention that you're visiting someone more than just a friend you need to be prepared to prove you intend to leave, that means showing strong ties to home country (job, property, medical appointments, family etc)